# C# WinForms: Data in report is not printing.

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

I am new to C# and reports. What am I doing wrong or missing?

I have searched and searched and for the life of me can't figure this out.

I am using C# Windows Forms Application. I have report2.rdlc and everything works great in the report viewer, the text boxes and data in the tablix print as expected. When I print directly to the printer without using the report viewer, the text boxes print, but the data in the tablix does not print. Provided below is a screenshot of the Report Data window along with the coding and explanation.

[Report Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa9Na.png)

StatusCodes.cs form: Contains print button that has DialogResult. If "Yes" is clicked, StatusCodePreview.cs form opens. This has the report viewer (no problems here). If "No" is clicked, this triggers PrintWithoutReportViewer.cs and the report is printed directly to the default printer (problem: only text boxes and column headers are printing, data is not).

```
private void btn_CodePrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var message = "Do you wish to preview the report before printing?";
        var title = "Preview Report";
        DialogResult dg = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dg == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            StatusCodePreview scp = new StatusCodePreview();
            scp.Show();
        }
        else if (dg == DialogResult.No)
        {
            DataTable dt = new StatusCodesPrintDataSet.DataTable1DataTable();
            LocalReport report = new LocalReport {ReportEmbeddedResource = "Toolbar.Report2.rdlc"};
            report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("StatCodePrintDataSet1", dt));
            
            report.PrintToPrinter();
        }
    }
```

Code for PrintWithoutReportViewer.cs

```
public static class PrintWithoutReportViewer
{
    private static int m_CurrentPageIndex;
    private static IList<Stream> m_Streams;
    private static PageSettings m_PageSettings;

    public static Stream CreateStream(string name, string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_Streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    public static void Export(LocalReport report, bool print = true)
    {
        PaperSize paperSize = m_PageSettings.PaperSize;
        Margins margins = m_PageSettings.Margins;

        
        string deviceInfo = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "<DeviceInfo>" +
            "<OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>" +
            "<PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth>" +
            "<PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight>" +
            "<MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop>" +
            "<MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft>" +
            "<MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight>" +
            "<MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom>" +
            "</DeviceInfo>",
            ToInches(margins.Top),
            ToInches(margins.Left),
            ToInches(margins.Right),
            ToInches(margins.Bottom),
            ToInches(paperSize.Height),
            ToInches(paperSize.Width));

        Warning[] warnings;
        m_Streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
            out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_Streams)
            stream.Position = 0;

        if (print)
        {
            Print();
            //PrintDialog startPrint = new PrintDialog();
            //startPrint.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    
    public static void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream pageToPrint = m_Streams[m_CurrentPageIndex];
        pageToPrint.Position = 0;

        
        using (Metafile pageMetaFile = new Metafile(pageToPrint))
        {
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                    e.PageBounds.Left - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                    e.PageBounds.Top - (int)e.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                    e.PageBounds.Width,
                    e.PageBounds.Height);

            
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(pageMetaFile, adjustedRect);

            
            m_CurrentPageIndex++;
            e.HasMorePages = m_CurrentPageIndex < m_Streams.Count;
        }
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        if (m_Streams == null || m_Streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_CurrentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }

    public static void PrintToPrinter(this LocalReport report)
    {
        m_PageSettings = new PageSettings();
        ReportPageSettings reportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings();

        m_PageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize;
        m_PageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins;

        Export(report);
    }

    public static void DisposePrint()
    {
        if (m_Streams != null)
        {
            foreach (Stream stream in m_Streams)
                stream.Close();
            m_Streams = null;
        }
    }

    private static string ToInches(int hundrethsOfInch)
    {
        double inches = hundrethsOfInch / 100.0;
        return inches.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "in";
    }
}
```

I was originally trying to print using PrintDialog (I was wanting this option to allow user to still be able to select a printer), but that doesn't work at all and just led me to getting so frustrated. I am now just trying to use Print();

Like I said at the beginning, I am new at this and I'm lost. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: What version are you ReportExecution are you using? I thought you had to call RenderStream() on each of the streamsIDs returned.

Comment: Sorry that it took so long to answer. When I checked Report2.rdlc, it is showing http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition. When I check the report server it is showing http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition. I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for.

Comment: RAD - Ignore my comment above, I see this is local report processing.